# How to get UserName from Computer?

Tags: windows, vb.net, active-directory, windowsdomainaccount

I'm searching to get back the String on the red block.
[image: The red block is the string]

I already tried the following code:

```
Environment.UserName
My.User.Name
SystemInformation.UserName
System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name
Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop)
Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("%USERNAME%"))
```

But this code don't work, because the computer of my company uses a domain, and the String that I need is different  as the user.
The user is composed only by the name, and the string is composed by the name and the first name of the employees.

Comment: Is this what you are looking for? https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ts4s4536(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: No, this one give me only the user, i already tried this one too, but thank you

Comment: What about just `Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("%USERNAME%")`

Comment: `Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("%USERNAME%")` give me a empty String

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found what I need [here](http://www.shulerent.com/2010/02/03/getting-active-directory-info-for-the-current-user-in-vb-net-in-2-lines/)

We have to import that :

> “System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement”
>   “System.DirectoryServices”

And write this two lines to get back the red block.

```
Dim currentADUser As System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.UserPrincipal
currentADUser = System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.UserPrincipal.Current
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using either

```
HttpContext.Current.Server.MachineName
```

or

```
System.Environment.MachineName;
```

Comment: That give me the Computer name, i don't need it, I need to get the red block on the photo. And I think is a Windows vairiable like %USERNAME%, but I can't find it.

Comment: From the ComputerName, You'll have to construct the complete path. That's the way it works. Or are you looking to read the path of a file?

Comment: I don't need the path, I just need the string in the red block. I've to open a excel-file who is called like this red block.

Comment: Isn't that the MachineName?

Comment: No, press your Windows button, click on the user and you get the the same window as the photo.